# Compare dates regardless of time(MSSQL)

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I Used this Store procedure to return data from special date . my QueueDate type is datetime , but when i want use = in Where Clause it return 0 , i want all field that are in one day independence in time of field.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_GET_QUEUESINFO_BY_DATE]
AS
BEGIN
declare @date2 datetime
set @date2= '2012-09-21'
select COUNT(QueueID) ,
sum(case when QueueNumIn != 0 THEN 1 else 0 end) as 'InQueue',
sum(case when QueueNumOut != 0 THEN 1 else 0 end) as  'OutQueue'
from Queue where QueueDate >= @date2 -- QueueDate = @date2
END
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can `CAST` the column name to change the datatype from `DATETIME` to `DATE` (*prior to version 2008+*). Try,

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_GET_QUEUESINFO_BY_DATE]
AS
BEGIN
declare @date2 datetime
set @date2= '2012-09-21'
select COUNT(QueueID) ,
       sum(case when QueueNumIn != 0 THEN 1 else 0 end) as 'InQueue',
       sum(case when QueueNumOut != 0 THEN 1 else 0 end) as  'OutQueue'
from Queue 
where CAST(QueueDate as DATE) >= @date2 -- QueueDate = @date2
END
```

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server, correct?

To compare just the date component of a `DateTime` value and your are using SQL Server 2008 or higher, you can, as noted cast/convert to a `Date` datatype. Something like this should do you:

```
select *
from foo
where convert(date,foo.someDateTimeColumn) = '2012-10-27'
```

For **any** version of SQL Server the following will work:

```
select *
from foo
where convert(datetime,convert(varchar,foo.someDateTimeColumn,112),112) = '2012-10-27'
```

The above, using the 112 style, converts the datetime value to a compact form ISO 8601 date string 'yyyymmdd' and then converts that back to a datetime value.

Alternatively, for any version of SQL Server, you can test against a time period:

```
declare
  @dtNow datetime
set @dtNow = current_timestamp

declare
  @TodayStartOfDay datetime ,
  @TodayEndOfDay   datetime
set @TodayStartOfDay = convert(datetime,convert(varchar,@dtNow,112),112)
set @TodayEndOfDay   = dateadd(ms,-3,datetime(day,1,@dtFrom))

...

select *
from foo
where foo.someDateTimeColumn between @TodayStartOfDay and @TodayEndOfDay
```

The advantage of this approach is that any indices on your DateTime column are eligible for use by the query optimizer.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY,@date2, QueueDate)=0
```